# Symfony " 'use' statement for another namespace?" issue

Tags: symfony, namespaces

I have a problem with namespaces in connecting my entity class to an abstract-type class.

I needed to create an `AbstractType` Class I called **BlogFactory**. I intent to use it in my the `createAction` function of my **BlogController.php** Entity class for creating blog entries.

My `BlogFactory` class is created in the **Form/Blog** directory of my bundle, as the tree structure shows.

```
.
.
.
src/Blogger/BlogBundle/
├── Controller
│   ├── BlogController.php
│   └── PageController.php
├── DataFixtures
│   └── ORM
│       └── BlogFixtures.php
├── Entity
│   ├── Blog.php
│   ├── Blog.php~
│   └── Enquiry.php
├── Form
│   ├── Blog
│   │   ├── BlogFactory.php
│   │   └── Factory.php
│   └── EnquiryType.php
├── Resources
│   ├── config
│   │   ├── config.yml
│   │   ├── routing.yml
│   │   └── services.yml
.
.
.
```

In the `BlogController.php` entity class, I include the following **use** instruction:

```
namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Blogger\BlogBundle\Form\Blog\BlogFactory;

class BlogController extends Controller{
.
.
.
```

with the following `createAction` function:

```
public function createAction(){   
        $form = $this->createForm(new BlogFactory(), new Blog(), 
            array(
                'action' => $this->generateUrl('blog_create'),
                'method' => 'POST',
            )
        );

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label'=>'Create'));
        return $form;
    }
```

Here is the code in my `BlogFactory` class:

```
namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class BlogFactory extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('title');
        $builder->add('author');
        $builder->add('blog');
        $builder->add('image');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'newblog';
    }
}
```

However, my problem is I get the following error:

```
The autoloader expected class "Blogger\BlogBundle\Form\Blog\BlogFactory" to be defined in file "/var/www/Symfony-Blog/src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Form/Blog/BlogFactory.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo
```

I'm quite stuck and not sure how to resolve this.

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by Gnucki, I added **namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Form\Blog;** to my BlogFactory.php and **use Blogger\BlogBundle\Form\Blog\BlogFactory;** to BlogController.php, and got the slightly different error below:

```
Attempted to load class "Blog" from namespace "Blogger\BlogBundle\Controller".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

Comment: You should be using `use Blogger\BlogBundle\Form\Blog\BlogFactory`. With no `use` the `new BlogFactory` is being treated as in the same directory.

Comment: As in the same namespace.

Comment: In your controller, you need to use Blogger\BlogBundle\Form\Blog\BlogFactory; or need use whole path in create form new BlogFactory()

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Would you mind looking over the code again as I'm certain I'm doing what you suggested but I still get the same error. I apologize because I pasted the wrong abstract class first time around - I have now corrected that.

Comment: you might have forgotten to install a dependency. This also causes "forget a "use" statement" error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a problem of mapping between your directories and namespaces:

You say that the class `BlogFactory` is in `Form/Blog/BlogFactory.php` and you define the class in the namespace `Blogger\BlogBundle\Form`.

You should use this namespace for your class `BlogFactory`:

```
namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Form\Blog;
```

Then specify these use statements in your controller:

```
use Blogger\BlogBundle\Form\Blog\BlogFactory;
use Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Blog;
```

**Explanation:**

In a simple PHP application, you use some [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) or [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) to include files into each other. But it is really boring. Instead, you can use an [autoload function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) to handle that. Symfony2 implements it in a manner that a namespace is mapped on a directory in a logical way. For instance, class `Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Blog` can be found in `/Blogger/BlogBundle/Entity/Blog.php`.

If you want to use the class in another one (with another namespace (so another directory)), you can use for example:

```
new \Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Blog();
```

or:

```
use Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Blog;

new Blog();
```

Imagine, you are in another namespace whitout that use:

```
namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Controller;

new Blog();
```

The class `Blog` will be interpreted as class `Blogger\BlogBundle\Controller\Blog`.

```
namespace Blogger\BlogBundle\Controller;

use Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Blog;

new Blog();
```

Now, with the use, `Blog` will be interpreted as `Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Blog`.

See [namespaces in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) for more informations.

Comment: Thanks Gnucki. I added an update indicating a new error after implementing your suggestion.

Comment: Add `use Blogger\BlogBundle\Entity\Blog;` in your controller.

Comment: Thank you. That got it working. Could you offer some explanation so I better understand how this works and how it fix it - next time? Thanks again

Comment: I added an explanation. Tell me if it is not clear or if you want some details.

Answer (score -1):

Note: You can transform

```
$builder->add('title');
    $builder->add('author');
    $builder->add('blog');
    $builder->add('image');
```

to

```
$builder
    ->add('title')
    ->add('author')
    ->add('blog')
    ->add('image')
;
```

Comment: Would be nice if you'd explain why (so because method returns object itself).